# The meaning of "what chances the day offered of return,"

Tags: meaning

Findlayson staggered to his feet and shook himself. His bead swam and ached, but the work of the opium was over, and, as he sluiced his forehead in a pool, the Chief Engineer of the Kashi Bridge was wondering how he had managed to fall upon the island, **what chances the day offered of return, and, above all, how his work stood.**

This is from "The Bridge Builders" by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-bridge-builders.htm

I don't understand the meaning of
what chances the day offered of return,

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: I don't have time right now to read the story, but the synopsis says "Findlayson is swept down the river at night in a small boat, onto an island". So presumably he is wondering what chance he has of getting back upriver to the bridge he is building.

Comment: Kate,thank you very much for your comment. It is very helpful!